# How to cache user input in form

Tags: php, html, caching, input

I'm trying to cache the user input in my form. My code is:

```
    echo '
<form method="POST">
    Name:<br /><input class="contact_name" type="text" name="contact_name" maxlength="32" placeholder="Enter Name" /><br />
    Email:<br /><input class="contact_email" type="text" name="contact_email" maxlength="50" placeholder="Email Address" /><br />
    Subject:<br /><input class="contact_subject" type="text" name="contact_subject" maxlength="50" placeholder="Subject Line" /><br />
    Message:<br /><textarea class="message_area" name="contact_message" rows="10" cols="50" maxlength="1000" placeholder="Message ..." /></textarea><br />
    <input class="submit_button" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
';
```

I tried searching for the answer and the only thing I found was adding:

```
<?php if(isset($contact_name)) { echo $contact_name; } ?>
```

This however does not work for me as my form is within a PHP echo and I'm trying to make a basic wordpress plugin. Whenever I bring the form outside the echo and , the style messes up and the form style itself breaks. So I was wondering if I can keep my form inside my echo along with a placeholder and be able to cache user inputs so when an error displays cause they didn't fill one of the spots out, it won't erase everything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Then, just drop the `echo` and switch to HTML mode:

```
?>
<form method="post">
Name:<br /><input ... value="<?php echo (isset($contact_name) ? htmlspecialchars($contact_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') : ''; ?>" />
...
<?php
```

If you need this as a string, you could use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
?>
<input ... />
<?php

echo ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: "This however does not work for me as my form is within a PHP echo and I'm trying to make a basic wordpress plugin. Whenever I bring the form outside the echo and , the style messes up and the form style itself breaks. So I was wondering if I can keep my form inside my echo along with a placeholder and be able to cache user inputs so when an error displays cause they didn't fill one of the spots out, it won't erase everything."

Comment: @KaiYue That makes no sense, `echo 'html stuff';` is essentially the same as `?>html stuff<?php`.

Comment: Like I said, I tried that but I don't know why the entire form breaks off and moves somewhere to the top. Should I code it in php and html first before trying to convert it into a plugin?

Comment: @KaiYue No clue, but you could use output buffering; added as an example.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, I'll try that and just start from scratch again.